# How to motivate oneself to learn unappealing programming technologies?

Tags: software-industry, career-development

While I am not currently looking for a new job, I occasionally peruse the job boards on the off chance I find something more in line with my interests. Many of the positions I see have a laundry list of requirements which I don't possess, or find unattractive.

How can I motivate myself to learn these skills that I wouldn't pick up otherwise?

Comment: Well, what **is** your motivation? If you find them unattractive, why look for a job that makes use of them?

Comment: If you don't like the requirements, why would you want to spend 8 hours/day every day using these technologies? Would it not be better to look for a job where you like the stuff you're going to do?

Comment: "on the off chance I find something in line with my interests" -- if the list is unattractive, then by your own words, it is not what you're looking for.

Comment: OK, for example, I know Java, but the only jobs around here that ask for Java  experience, also want Javascript, which I don't know and am not interested in.

Comment: @HerbWolfe Then they are Web development shops; do you want to do that? If so, then yes, you must learn JavaScript.

Comment: @Brandin not particularly, but that's pretty much the only language I have used professionally. Microsoft killed off Foxpro, and what I'm doing now is about the only field in which it's still used.

Answer (score 6):

> How can I motivate myself to learn these skills that I wouldn't pick
>   up otherwise?

You can motivate yourself by realizing what you might be doing to yourself and your career if you don't learn more skills.

If you refuse to learn the technologies/techniques that are in demand, you'll narrow the range of possible employers, perhaps to the point where you are unlikely to land a job. The narrower your focus, the fewer the possibilities.

For example, you know Java, but you find that employers want both Java and Javascript. Javascript should be rather simple for someone like you to learn. But if you refuse to do so, you may be eliminating every employer who requires (or prefers) developers with Javascript knowledge - and that is quite a few employers.

In general, employers don't want to hire folks with the attitude that they aren't motivated to do anything but a narrow range of tasks. They want generalists and workers willing to simply "get things done" rather than special snowflakes who only do one or two things then aren't "motivated" to do anything else. Work occasionally involves doing this that some consider "unattractive". Few jobs allows you to do only the "fun" parts.

Software these days is an ever-changing landscape. The technologies and processes that are in favor today will fade - probably sooner than later. The software professionals who will succeed are the ones who understand this and are lifelong learners. If you refuse to pick up new abilities, you will quickly fall by the wayside.

Visual Foxpro-centric jobs must be few and far between these days. You simply *must* widen your scope of capabilities to keep your skill viable in today's market.

Maybe those thoughts can motivate you.

Comment: Good answer. The motivation is the reason, if you like to be in that position so you can come here and ask us then you live a life fulfilled. If you enjoy the frustration or questioning their decisions then you're in the correct place. Is money the motivation, what did you want to get out of being there. Decide what motivates you, and seek out somewhere that provides what you want. You want words to motivate you: "You can do it, champ" - there you go. Money motivates me.

Answer (score 1):

Programming is about getting things done.

Have you got anything that you want done and could be done by a computer? Have you got something that could be done better? Could it reasonably be done in a technology you're interested in learning?

That's how I learn things - perhaps learning-by-doing will work for you.

The fun of solving problems you can probably find in most languages - any language is just one way of expressing of a solution. Once you get used to solving problems and expressing yourself in a language, you stop caring so much about its idiosyncracies.

Answer (score 1):

Don't learn skills, create applications.

Few programmers find programming languages themselves "attractive" or "fun" (some do). But many like to actually program something.

Chose to create a hobby project which you're actually interested in, and which benefits from the skill you intend to learn. For example, if you want to learn SQL, find a fun little hobby project that benefits from using an SQL database, then implement that project.

The tricky part is to find projects that actually benefit from the new technology. For example: if the aforementioned SQL project could easily be done with a dictionary and a binary serializer - assuming you are familiar with these and unfamiliar with SQL - then the project is a bad fit for learning SQL.